# How to make keyboard with multiple tabs/sections in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have successfully made a very basic custom keyboard for Android based off of [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615).

Now that I finished that, I was wondering, is it possible to make a keyboard in Android that has multiple tabs.

An example would be normally the keyboard has the letters A-Z but if a user clicks a button on the top then the keyboard will switch to numbers 1 - 10 and if the user clicks another button on the top the keyboard will switch to greek letters.

Another way I could explain it is that, is there anyway to programmatically change which xml layout file the keyboard will use?

Here is a example. Here the "tabs" are the clock,smileyface,crown,flower,car,triangle and textface symbols at the top of the keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple fix.

The service class I use contains these two variables:

```
private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;
```

Here is the code for what happens when the button is pressed:

```
case 37:
            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty2);
            kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            break;
```

The button switches the XML layout of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think that tabs is the best approach for you.

I believe that the best approach for you will be to create CustomViews for every layout, add a FrameLayout to the screen and programatically add the view to the layout, removing the others with removeAllViews. Here is the tutorial for building the CustomViews: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/custom-views/index.html

Another option is to add all the custom views to the layout and change programatically which will be visible.

An option that I don´t recomend is to work with fragment, the lifecycle of the fragment is complicated and will just annoy you.

Comment: I need a little bit more detail in order to understand how to integrate this into my custom keyboard app. I am not sure how this will all work since I think I have to use a KeyboardView and not something such as a FrameLayout.

Comment: @Roymunson if you need more info, you should provide more detail in your question.